# How to model users in the system?

Tags: rest, authentication, database-design

I am working on system that will manage orders. Orders can be created via admin or via customer. Employee can take orders and change it's status.
My system should have three global types of users:

1. Admin - this type of users mostly uses WEB interface. Admins have different access levels, so some of them can only create orders, and others - edit core info about pricing and so on.
2. Customer - this type of users uses customer's mobile app. Main action is to add and cancel orders.
3. Employee - this type of users uses employee's mobile app. Employees can see open orders, assign themselves to orders and change order statuses.

Also, Customer and Employee can be authorised with phone number, that can be changed at some time (independently of each other). Admins can be authorised with uname + pword.

Current solution has one table for Admins, one for Customers and one for Employees.

So first part of question is how to structure database properly?

The second part is about authorising in REST api. In current solution I have three endpoints, that are authireses usertype independently.

- admins/auth
- customers/auth
- employees/auth

And my thoughts is to keep three tables as is, because each usertype is slightly different concept and really independent. And keep authorisation as is, but add something like roles and privileges to auth token to restrict access for some resources.

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out? I am stuck in a similar problem and would love some advice!

Comment: @mtshaikh I would go with separate tables, because types are independent (really depend on domain). Some will prefer to model user details and auth info and connect them to provide agile authorisation.